# Understanding of the following assembly code from CSAPP

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I am recently reading CSAPP and I have a question about example of assembly code. This is an example from CSAPP, the code is followed:

```
    long pcount_goto
    (unsigned long x) {
    long result = 0;
    result += x & 0x1;
    x >>= 1;
    if(x) goto loop;
    return result;
```

￼
And the corresponding assembly code is:

```
   movl    $0, %eax     #  result = 0
   .L2:                 # loop:
    movq    %rdi, %rdx
    andl    $1, %edx    #  t = x & 0x1
    addq    %rdx, %rax   #  result += t
    shrq    %rdi         #  x >>= 1
    jne .L2                 #  if (x) goto loop
    rep; ret
```

The questions I have may look naive since I am very new to assembly code but I will be grateful is someone can help me with these questions.

1. what's the difference between %eax, %rax, (also %edx, %rdx). I have seen them occur in the assembly code but they seems to refer to the same space/address. What's the point of using two different names?
2. In the code

   ```
   andl    $1, %edx    #  t = x & 0x1
   ```

   I understand that %edx now stores the t, but where does x goes then?
3. In the code

   ```
   shrq    %rdi
   ```

   I think

   ```
    shrq   1, %rdi
   ```

   should be better?
4. For

   ```
   jne .L2                 #  if (x) goto loop
   ```

   Where does if (x) goes? I can't see any judgement.

Comment: The source is missing the `loop:` label (although it's not hard to imagine where it belongs). And if you struggle with what is `edx` vs `rdx`, then after Jester answer you should have been like "aha, but if the `and` does mask only 32b, why the `add` is using 64b" ... and the answer to that is, that the x86-64 will clear upper 32b of register when `e` variant is used, so `andl $1,%edx` has same result as `andq $1,%rdx`, but 1 byte shorter machine code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are really basic questions, a little research of your own should have answered all of them. Anyway,

1. The `e` registers are the low 32 bits of the `r` registers. You pick one depending on what size you need. There are also 16 and 8 bit registers. Consult a basic architecture manual.
2. The `and` instruction modifies its argument, it's not `a = b & c`, it's `a &= b`.
3. That would be `shrq $1, %rdi` which is valid, and `shrq %rdi` is just an alias for it.
4. `jne` examines the zero flag which is set earlier by `shrq` automatically if the result was zero.

Comment: The course doesn't contain too much detail. Thanks for the answer ！

Comment: @LAWRENCE For particular instruction you can check the short reference guide like http://x86.renejeschke.de/ first, but for overall x86 CPU architecture like registers and similar, search for some book or tutorial probably. There are always also the official docs from Intel available, it's only few thousands of pages in pdf (still taking a look over content table may be worth it). Saying "course doesn't contain too much detail" in age of Internet... weird. Although they could have gave you some recommended literature.